# The 'is' operator cannot be applied to an operand of a static type

Tags: c#, nullable

What does this error mean in this context?

```
if (value == null)
    return "";

if (value is Nullable && ((INullable)value).IsNull) //error on this line
    return "";

if (value is DateTime)
{
    if (((DateTime)value).TimeOfDay.TotalSeconds == 0)
        return ((DateTime)value).ToString ("yyyy-MM-dd");
    return ((DateTime)value).ToString ("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
}
```

I searched but didn't get any information on this error. I am trying this on Mono (2.10.8.1). This is a project actually meant for Windows, but when I tried to compile it in Monodevelop, I got this error.

Comment: @AndreCalil: Could be, wouldn't matter.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
if (value is Nullable
```

It thinks you're talking about the [static class `System.Nullable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fs5xdbk8) rather than the [`System.Nullable<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b3h38hb0.aspx) struct.

Perhaps you meant:

```
if (value is INullable ...)
```

?

Note that if `value` is of compile-time type `object`, then it will *never* be a `Nullable<T>`, as boxing a null value would give a null reference, and boxing a non-null value would give a boxed value of the underlying type.

If you think there's still something else which you need to achieve, please specify what you're trying to do.

Comment: +1 I think you're right, the OP most likely meant `INullable`.

Comment: Hi Jon. This is from this project I saw on reddit a while ago: https://github.com/mavispuford/RedditSaveTransfer. I did not grasp the project fully yet. I received this error when I first compiled it. I changed it to INullable and it worked fine. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

The type `System.Nullable` is a static type--which means an instance can't be created.  Therefore `value` can never be a type of `Nullable`.

The Microsoft C# compiler doesn't have this error--so, anyone using Visual Studio won't get this error.  So, the people who created RedditSaveTransfer seem to have used Visual Studio.  Compiling the same in MonoDevelop obviously has this extra error.

I don't know anything about this code, so I don't know the intention of what they're trying to do here.  Clearly `value` can never be of type `Nullable`, so the whole `if` statement will always be false.  So, I assume, it would be safe to simply remove the block from the code.

But, based on the code it looks like it's trying to check if the value is some sort of `SqlTypes.INullable`.  In which case I might do something like:

```
INullable nullable = value as INullable;
if(nullable != null && nullable.IsNull)
   return "";
```

But, that will produce different results than the original code; and I don't know if that's a good thing or a bad thing.

I agree with Jon that possibly this was a typo for `value is INullable`; but, I don't know for sure.

Comment: Looks like you were the only one to try to answer the original question (rather then solve the problem).

Comment: Thank you Peter. This makes a lot of sense.

Comment: @Trisped  Well, we don't know what the problem is other than there's a compile error.

Comment: It compiles for me in VS2015 and then in VS2013 I got this error.

Comment: @ppumkin If in VS2015 (which uses the Roslyn-based C# 6.0 compiler) you compile with __feature strict__, then you get `Error CS7023 The second operand of an 'is' or 'as' operator may not be static type 'Nullable'`